# Python Calling in the wrong type of type of variable

Tags: python, sorting

I'm having some problems with my sorting algorithim

```
def Rank_Players():
    Score_List = []
    Sorted_List = []
    for x in List_Of_Players:
        Score_List.append([x,List_Of_Players[x][1]])

    while Score_List:
        maximum = Score_List[x]
        for x in Score_List:
            if Score_List[x][1] > maximum[1]:
                maximum = Score_List[x][1]
        Sorted_List.append(maximum)
        Score_List.remove(maximum)
    print (Sorted_List)
```

First let me explain what it does as i've not really done any commenting.

First List_Of_Players is a global dictionary that hold player information given using a different procedure

1. Creates two arrays and then appends the dictionary reference number
   and there total points to the Score_List in the format [x,points]
2. While the Score_List has values It will go through the list checking
   if they are an array with a great number of points
3. The maximum is appended to the Sorted_List and removed from the the Score_List and printed to the screen (right now to see if it works)

My problem is that despite pointing to an integer in Line 11 , Python belives that i'm comparing using a list.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

To try and fix this issue i've tried changing the two maximum declerations to

```
maximum = int(Score_list[x])
```

Thank you for reading , this is my first time trying to use a sorting algorithim so theres bound to be more mistakes but if anybody can help with the TypeError I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Please fix your indentation and add your input and expected output. What is `List_of_Players`

Comment: `Score_List.append([x,List_Of_Players[x][1]])` adds lists elements to your list which you access with `for x in Score_List`. So `x` is indeed a list not an integer.

Comment: also in the while loop: `maximum = Score_List[x]`, what's the `x` here, you haven't defined it.

Comment: You may want to edit the question title, ```Calling in a lnteger``` really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @wwii Your right it isn't very clear i've just changed that now if it's still not clear enough feel free to suggest a better title , i'm still quite new to this @ IanAuld I don't quite understand what im missing in terms of indentation. Edited to explain List_Of_Players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this fragment:

```
List_Of_Players[x][1]
```

it becomes clear that your list of players is a list of lists.

From this fragment:

```
for x in List_Of_Players:
```

it becomes clear that x is hence a list.

So in this fragment:

```
List_Of_Players[x][1]
```

you're using a list as an index, which is what the Python interpreter complains about.

Comment: Thank you for breaking down the soultion , really helped with my understanding and cleared up a mis-conception.

Answer (score 0):

at this line:

```
for x in Score_List:
```

x is a list (not an integer usable as a list index): `[y,List_Of_Players[y][1]]`
but you use it like this: `if Score_List[x][1]`

Answer (score 0):

The thing that's wrong here is that when you loop through a list, the iterator - here `x` - is the *value*, not the index. So instead of

```
    for x in Score_List:
        if Score_List[x][1] > maximum[1]:
            maximum = Score_List[x][1]
```

you should do

```
    for x in Score_List:
        if x[1] > maximum[1]:
            maximum = x[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for providing working code and explaining the issue clearly.